# Troubleshooting CakePHP form submission

Tags: forms, cakephp

I recently set up the ability to tag posts on my site. I had everything working fine. Then as I was wrapping up I tested all my admin side forms again. The Add Tag form no longer does anything. It doesn't even flash an error or redirect after submission. The page just reloads at the same URL. The only changes to the site I have made since initial testing was move the forms to the admin side of the dev site. Here is some code to hopefully reveal what the mystery is. Also my edit tag form is doing similar thing. It has no flash message but redirects back to the index, like its supposed to but with no changes made to the tag. Ill include the edit code as well.

Add.ctp in src/Template/Admin/Tags/Add.ctp

```
<div class="tags form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($tag) ?>
<div class="form-group">
<fieldset>
    <h1 class="page-header">New Tag</h1>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name', ['class' => 'form-control']);
    ?>
</fieldset>
</div>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Here is my Add funciton in my TagsController:

```
public function add()
{   
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
    $tag = $this->Tags->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $tag = $this->Tags->patchEntity($tag, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Tags->save($tag)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The tag has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The tag could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('tag'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['tag']);
}
```

Here is my Edit funciton in my TagsController:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
    $tag = $this->Tags->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $tag = $this->Tags->patchEntity($tag, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Tags->save($tag)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The tag has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The tag could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('tag'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['tag']);
}
```

Edit.ctp in src/Template/Admin/Tags/Edit.ctp

```
<div class="tags form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($tag) ?>
<div class="form-group">
<fieldset>
    <h1 class="page-header">Edit Tag</h1>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class' => 'form-control'));
    ?>
</fieldset>
</div>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Just as a side note. I started getting errors when creating a new post as well.

**General error: 1364 Field 'section_id' doesn't have a default value**

I did go into my DB and give the field a default value. But then when I fill out the form for a new post again, the error just moves to the next table column. I am assuming they are some how related since they popped up at the same time and because tags and posts are related to each other.

TagsTable:

```
class TagsTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('tags');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->hasMany('PostsTags', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('name');

    return $validator;
}
}
```

Tags Entity:

```
class Tag extends Entity
{

/**
 * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
 *
 * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
 * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
 * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => false,
    'id' => false
];

}
```

When I place `<?php debug($tag); ?>` into my add.ctp view this is the out put it gives me:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Tag) {

'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [],
'[dirty]' => [],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Tags'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, in question always post debug pathEntity output, in your case `debug($tag)`, also Tag Entity, your validation code, and how looks your db  tags table.

Answer:

> > General error: 1364 Field 'section_id' doesn't have a default value

This means that you have not passed a value for this field.

You can change that table field to accept null or empty value and/or set default if not passed from application, or make validation  in your TagsTable to be sure if submitted data valid before send to db.

**After question updated:**

```
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => false, <---- should be true
    'id' => false
];
```

**This means that all fields except id are accessible**

Comment: I have updated question with the Tag Entity, TagsTable and output from debug($tag) placed in my add.ctp view. Thanks in advance.